# Azure mysql DB with entity frameworkcore error

Tags: mysql, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-mysql-database

i just finished building my application and came to find out that the azure mysql db i created is giving me some errors. When i use a normal mysql db locally during development everything works fine and perfectly, when i seeded some data into the azure db from an external api the db saved the changes, but the only problem is it cannot see or save changes generated by my application. I am using the pomelo mysql data client 3.2.4 .
when i try registering a user into the azure db, i get this error:

```
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (138ms) [Parameters=[@__normalizedUserName_0='?' (Size = 256)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `a`.`Id`, `a`.`AccessFailedCount`, `a`.`Bio`, `a`.`ConcurrencyStamp`, `a`.`CreatedAt`, `a`.`Email`, `a`.`EmailConfirmed`, `a`.`Gender`, `a`.`GravatarP
rofileImage`, `a`.`Instagram`, `a`.`LockoutEnabled`, `a`.`LockoutEnd`, `a`.`NormalizedEmail`, `a`.`NormalizedUserName`, `a`.`PasswordHash`, `a`.`PhoneNumber`, `a`.
`PhoneNumberConfirmed`, `a`.`SecurityStamp`, `a`.`Twitch`, `a`.`Twitter`, `a`.`TwoFactorEnabled`, `a`.`UserName`, `a`.`Youtube`
      FROM `AspNetUsers` AS `a`
      WHERE `a`.`NormalizedUserName` = @__normalizedUserName_0
      LIMIT 1
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Persistance.DataContext'.
      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'a.CreatedAt' in 'field list'
       ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'a.CreatedAt' in 'field list'
         at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 806
         at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 51
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Data.MySqlClient/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cached
Procedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Data.MySqlC
lient/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 391
         at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBeh
avior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 62
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/My
Sql.Data.MySqlClient/MySqlCommand.cs:line 257
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancella
tionToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancella
tionToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancella
tionToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken
cancellationToken)
         at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucc
eeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'a.CreatedAt' in 'field list'
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'a.CreatedAt' in 'field list'
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 806
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 51
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Data.MySqlClient/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProced
ures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Data.MySqlClient/
MySqlDataReader.cs:line 391
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior
ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 62
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Da
ta.MySqlClient/MySqlCommand.cs:line 257
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationTo
ken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationTo
ken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationTo
ken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancel
lationToken)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded,
 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
fail: Api.Middlewares.Errors.ErrorHandlingMiddleware[0]
      SERVER ERROR
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'a.CreatedAt' in 'field list'
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'a.CreatedAt' in 'field list'
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 806
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 51
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Data.MySqlClient/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProced
ures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Data.MySqlClient/
MySqlDataReader.cs:line 391
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior
ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 62
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Da
ta.MySqlClient/MySqlCommand.cs:line 257
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationTo
ken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationTo
ken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationTo
ken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancel
lationToken)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded,
 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken
 cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken
 cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserValidator`1.ValidateUserName(UserManager`1 manager, TUser user, ICollection`1 errors)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserValidator`1.ValidateAsync(UserManager`1 manager, TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.ValidateUserAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.CreateAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.CreateAsync(TUser user, String password)
   at Application.Auth.Register.Handler.Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\c#\Qlip\Application\Auth\Register.cs:
line 73
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at Api.Controllers.UserController.Register(Command command) in C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\c#\Qlip\api\Controllers\UserController.cs:line 22
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor execu
tor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionR
esultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask,
State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State
 next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope
scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Api.Middlewares.Errors.ErrorHandlingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\c#\Qlip\api\Middlewares\ErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 3
0
```

if i remove the azure mysql-db connection string and replace it with a local mysql connection string, the code works as expected.
my data context class is:

```
 public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }

        public DbSet<Clip> Clips { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserClip> UserClips { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DislikeUserClip> DislikeUserClips{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserFollowings> Followings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<View> Views { get; set; }
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserClip>().HasKey(uc => new {uc.ClipId, uc.ApplicationUserId});

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserClip>().HasOne(au => au.ApplicationUser).WithMany(au => au.UserClips)
                .HasForeignKey(au => au.ApplicationUserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserClip>().HasOne(c => c.Clip).WithMany(uc => uc.UserClips)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ClipId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<DislikeUserClip>().HasKey(duc => new {duc.ClipId, duc.ApplicationUserId});

            modelBuilder.Entity<DislikeUserClip>().HasOne(au => au.ApplicationUser).WithMany(au => au.DislikeUserClips)
                .HasForeignKey(au => au.ApplicationUserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<DislikeUserClip>().HasOne(c => c.Clip).WithMany(c => c.DislikeUserClips)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ClipId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserFollowings>().HasKey(uf => new {uf.ObserverId, uf.TargetId});

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserFollowings>().HasOne(o => o.Observer).WithMany(uf => uf.Followings)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.ObserverId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserFollowings>().HasOne(t => t.Target).WithMany(uf => uf.Followers)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.TargetId);
            
            // view table
            modelBuilder.Entity<View>().HasKey(v => new {v.ApplicationUserId, v.ClipId});

            modelBuilder.Entity<View>().HasOne(au => au.User).WithMany(v => v.Views)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ApplicationUserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<View>().HasOne(c => c.Clip).WithMany(v => v.Views).HasForeignKey(x => x.ClipId);
        }
    }
```

Note: when i spun up my app for the first time with the azure db it created all the tables my application needed, so i dont understand why this happens.
I have been banging my head in for the past few days because of this error, and i honestly cant figure out what is happening.
Please can anyone help me with this issue i am facing?

Comment: As from exception, you have resynchronisation in database schema and column `CreatedAt` is not present in Azure DB.

Comment: Thats weird, in my user entity class i have createdAt as a property. Do you suggest i add it manually or i try using ef core and adding a migration?

Comment: If there is already data in Azure, try to do that manually. Then for sure use migrations.

Comment: yeah, did it manually, everything works fine now. Thanks alot!, cant believe something as little as that breaks the whole codebase lol